# MYSQL count number of values which are repeated 2, 3 ,4 etc times

Tags: mysql, sql

The following sql will return a count of how many users have played a game from the game sessions table.

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT `userID`) as count FROM `game_sessions`
```

In this table "game_sessions", each row contains the details of a session of a user. Therefore there could be 3, 40 or even 500 rows with the same "userID". I understand the above query will find out how many distinct values of "useriD" there is, or in other terms, how many people have played AT LEAST ONE game.

How can I modify this query so I can find out how many people have played AT LEAST TWO games or AT LEAST 30 games, thus seeing how many userID's are repeated 2 times, 5 times, 10 times etc etc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to use `DISTINCT` keyword on this, just `COUNT` the records based on the each `userID`. try this one:

```
  SELECT userID, 
         COUNT(userID) TotalCount
    FROM game_sessions
GROUP BY userID
  HAVING COUNT(userID) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Think this will do the job:

```
select userID, count(userID)
from game_sessions
group by userID
having count(userID) > 2;
```

Change the number above to refine the query.